# How to show scrollbar in fancybox in iphone mobile responsive theme?

Tags: php, themes, prestashop

I have a problem to show the scrollbar in fancybox in mobile responsive theme of prestashop.
how can i show it.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some piece of code, so we can help you. Did some errors occur with your piece of code? Show us them!

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question to be more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have just upgraded Fancybox to its latest version, which is fully compliant with responsive templates.

This should resolve your issue, you can:

- Grab the modifications from the PrestaShop Github repo and apply them to your store
  https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/87a4b75df4a2e634cea2e5ef8484f73b5261566b

or

- Wait for the release of PrestaShop v1.5.5 (coming within a few weeks)

or

- Upgrade Fancybox to v2.1.5 yourself (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)